# How to include the whole author name in IEEE bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

In my bib library, the author is like "John, W.W.C", but when I make  bibliography
with bibliographystyle IEEETrans, it comes out like "W. John". Could you help me out? Thank you.

The bib lirary is as follow:

```
@article{articletocite, 
author={Jo, W.W.C. and Hu, J.}, 
journal={Journal}
title={Title}, 
year={2014},  
}
```

The tex file is as follow:

```
\documentclass[11pt, final, journal, letterpaper, doublecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{placeins}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} 
\bibliography{paper.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You need to write `author = {John, W. W. C.}` (with spaces) in order for BibTeX to see that the author has tree first names with the initials "W.", "W." and "C." and not that his their first name is "W.W.C". See also [BibTeX and authors with multiple initials (external blogpost)](http://diana.parno.net/thoughts/?p=140).

Comment: See also [BibTeX: Author's surname followed by multiple initials](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160862/35864), [Adapt BibTeX style to give all initials](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59810/35864), and a slightly longer explanation in the answer to [Displaying author's name in a bibliographic entry in the form: Surname, First Initial of Firstname](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131087/35864) (point 1 in the *addendum* is what you are looking for).